# Mysql sort by range

Tags: mysql

I have a database which looks like this :

```
NUM  / CNT
3    / 1
5    / 0
100  / 1
300  / 0
320  / 1
```

And I am looking for the query that will allow me to sort them by range and make sum of their count so I will  have something like this:

```
NUM     / CNT
0-100   / 2
100-400 / 1
```

I am wondering if this is possible using mysql querys .

Comment: use between query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SUM` with conditional aggregation on the value of each `NUM`:

```
SELECT '0-100' AS NUM,
       SUM(CASE WHEN NUM BETWEEN 0 AND 100 THEN CNT ELSE 0 END) AS CNT
FROM yourTable
UNION
SELECT '100-400' AS NUM,
       SUM(CASE WHEN NUM BETWEEN 100 AND 400 THEN CNT ELSE 0 END) AS CNT
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: IF YOU DON'T MIND WHY NOT BETWEEN SUM(CASE WHEN NUM BETWEEN 100 AND 400 THEN CNT ELSE 0 END) AS CNT

Comment: `SUM(CASE WHEN NUM <= 400 THEN CNT ELSE 0 END) AS CNT` this will add values that are even less than 100, it has to have `>` thing in it

Comment: You are all correct.  I refactored my query to unpivot and I forgot to change the `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

try this it will work same as you want.

```
SELECT '0-100' AS NUM,
       SUM(CASE WHEN NUM <= 100 THEN CNT ELSE 0 END) AS CNT
FROM  tableName
UNION
SELECT '100-400' AS NUM,
       SUM(CASE WHEN NUM > 100 THEN CNT ELSE 0 END) AS CNT
FROM  tableName
```